# Pig function to read characters after a separator

Tags: apache-pig

This is my input file

```
a1,hello.VDF
a2,rim.VIM
a3.dr.VDD
```

I need output as below

```
a1,VDF
a2,VIM
a3,VDD
```

My script is the following:

> myinput = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(',')
>   AS(t1:chararray,t2:chararray); foreached= FOREACH myinput GENERATE
>   t1,SUBSTRING(t2,INDEXOF(t2,'.',1),SIZE(t2));

It's throwing some error. Please help

Comment: Please define *some error*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
output = foreach myinput generate ((t1 matches '(.*)\\.(.*)'?SUBSTRING(t1, 0, 2):t1), (t1 matches '(.*)\\.(.*)'?SUBSTRING(t1, INDEXOF(t1,'.',0)+1, (int)SIZE(t1)):t2));
```

Answer (score 0):

[SIZE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#size) returns long, but [SUBSTRING](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#substring) takes integers, so you need to do conversion:

```
foreached = 
  FOREACH myinput GENERATE t1,SUBSTRING(t2,INDEXOF(t2,'.',1)+1,(int)SIZE(t2));
```